# Issue with MobileFirst SQLAdapter connecting to Oracle 11g DB

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm trying to create MobileFirst SQL adapter to connect to a Oracle 11G R2 Database. I get

> "Class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver not found in Worklight platform
>   or project"

error.

I have ensured that the Oracle driver (ojdbc6.jar) is present in the /server/lib folder of the MobileFirst project. The same has been added as an external jar in the build path. The same jar has been placed in //.ibm/mobilefirst/6.3.0/server/wlp/dev/spi/third-party and //.ibm/mobilefirst/6.3.0/server/wlp/lib.

The adapter xml used for connecting is:

```
<dataSourceDefinition>
    <driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClass>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.12:1521/FS11010</url>
    <user>TESTDB</user>
    <password>test123</password> 
</dataSourceDefinition>
```

Here the FS11010 is the service name.

The same works fine when we connect to a MySQL DB connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ojdbc6.jar in your server/lib folder then it should be included in your project's WAR file and hence be on the classpath. You should not need to put the jar anywhere else.

Suggest you check that the WAR file does indeed contain the jar file as expected.

Also restart your server, I don't think it should be necessary, but ...